# Countif - What criteria is faster

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do a lot of countifs and I am wondering what the fastest solution would be in terms of computing speed.

The criteria column contains `Yes`and `No`, all put there by the same formula, so no chance of misspelling. Now I wonder what would give the best performance:

`A1 = "No"`

`A1 = $Z$1`where `Z1 = No`

`Len(A1) = 2`

Or any other option, making use of for example `Left` or `Right` functions

Comment: Have you done any time tests? There are VB scripts available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: A question about speed / performance? Sounds a lot like it's better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are tons of similar questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+faster so IMHO this is the appropiate place for my question.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest, I have not as I don't know how to. I work on a MAC.